# In ReactJS, how do I pass a dynamic variable to the end of this.state? ex. this.state.{variable}

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In ReactJS, I want to do the following:

in constructor:

```
this.state = {
  activeStep: 1,
  step1Data: {},
  step2Data: {},
  step3Data: {}
}
```

in a function:

```
var step = 1;
var step1Data = this.state."step"+step+"Data";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `[]` member operator, like this:

```
var step1Data = this.state["step" + step + "Data"];
```

`obj.key` is the same as `obj['key']`

So if you have the key stored  in a variable, you can access it like `obj[variable]` (eg: with `var variable = 'key';` it will be the same as the previous two examples)

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to store your data in an array.

```
this.state = {
    activeStep: 1,
    stepData: [{}, {}, {}],
}
```

Then in your function...

```
var step = 1;
var step1Data = this.state.stepData[step];
```

Comment: Thanks alot! This might be a better and more dynamic approach!